# Installation of MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, wamp, mysql-workbench

I have installed the WAMP Server at my computer. Now I would like to install MySQL Workbench, but I don't know if I should install only Workbench, or if I should install the MySQL Community Server with all that it has.

Another doubt, If I install MySQL Community Server, will it replace the MySQL from WAMP? Or will I have two MySQL at my PC? They will get conflict?

Sorry, I don't have much experience with databases.

Thank you

Comment: MySQL Workbench comes without Server.

Comment: I like @Retro 's comment.  Go to the download page, and look at the "other downloads".  Don't download the link that does the "all in one", just get the workbench https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked several questions, I think this answers them all:

### If I have a DB already, should I install SQL Community Server, or Just the Workbench:

Just the workbench is fine.
From [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), don't download the top "all in one" package, go to the "other downloads" and choose the one that meets your needs.

### If I Install Community Server, will it replace MySQL from WAMP?

Technically you can have both, but yes, if you don't do it right, you can have some conflicts.

WAMP Supports running MySQL as a command line console (which closes when you close the console window), or as a windows service.  Installing the service is where you'd most likely get the conflicts.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Baronz for answering about the conflicts

Answer (score 0):

1. You can choose to install only MySQL Workbench. If It's so, when You are going to use Workbench, you need to start MySQL from Wamp.
2. You can have two or many installed MySQL servers, but they have to be in different routes (paths).
3. You can run two or many instances of MySQL Server, but they have to be in different ports.

Comment: Thank you @andreshg112, I didn't know that I would have to star MySQLfrom WAMP every time.

Comment: you don't have to start it every time.  If you install the service, and then set the service to start "automatically"  it will start on system boot (see image in my post)

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot it, because I deactivate "automatically start".

Answer (score 0):

No, in general you don't need to install the MySQL Community Server to install MySQL Workbench since it can connect to any MySQL server (local or remote). In my experience it can work with the MySQL provided by WAMP without problems.